# Get path elements in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a path information in one excel column in the following format:

/level1/level2/level3 etc.

The amount of levels is not spezified and the length of the level name is not fix:

For example:
/inf/press/january/article1
/inf/investors/

I want to separate the path components into separate columns, so that "inf", "press", "january", "article1" are in separate columns for further use in a pivot table.

How can I acomplish that with a formulas?

Comment: How about the Text to Columns function under the Data tab to split on `/`?

Comment: That is even better than a formula. It worked :-) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the Text to Columns function like so:

1. Select your data and go to Data > Text to Columns:

   [image]
2. In the wizard, use Delimiter:

   [image]
3. Pick 'Other' and pick forward slash:

   [image]
4. At this point, it should be safe to use 'Finish' instead of 'Next'. You would use 'Next' if you care about data types, especially to make sure that dates are obtained appropriately or if you want numbers to be converted to text.

The result for the above example is:

[image]

And it should be easy to rearrange the columns as suitable from this point.

Point to keep in mind: You should make sure there is no important information in the columns to the right of the column to split. Otherwise, you might lose them. You can of course insert some columns to the right before beginning at step 1 to ensure no data loss.